# How could I find out how many samples with loss > the median loss; and how many with loss using hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

How could I find out how many samples with loss > the median loss; and how many with loss using hierarchical clustering in R.
I am using the dataset Allstate claim severity, I think the numeric attributes are normalized these have values between 0 and 1

This my code:

```
claims<-read.csv("train.csv")
idx<-sample(1:dim(claims)[1],10000) #10000 random samples
claimsSample<-claims[idx,118:131] #retrieve the numeric features
distances<-dist(claimsSample,method="euclidean")
clusterClaims<-hclust(distances, method = "ward.D")
plot(clusterClaims)
clusterGroups<- cutree(clusterClaims,k=9)
```

So, How I find the median and the samples ???

Comment: Hi what do you mean by median? median of all samples, median of samples in the cluster?

Comment: Yes, If possible know the samples ??

Comment: For each of these clusters, find out how many samples with loss > the median loss; and how many with loss < the median loss

Comment: try the below @Fernando, not very sure what median you are referring to, but you can easily modify the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually provide an example dataset, or orientate other SO users to the dataset of interest. "loss" can mean a lot of things...

So we can try something like this:

```
#claims = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Architectshwet/Allstate-Claims-Severity-Data/master/Datasets/train.csv")
set.seed(111)
idx<-sample(nrow(claims),10000) 
claimsSample<-claims[idx,118:131] 
distances<-dist(claimsSample,method="euclidean")
clusterClaims<-hclust(distances, method = "ward.D")
clusterGroups<- cutree(clusterClaims,k=9)
```

The `clusterGroups` labels are given the same order as your rows, so below I get a vector (TRUE/FALSE) that represents whether an observation in your claimsSample is more than the median in claimsSample, and table it according to the group:

```
results = table(clusterGroups,claims$loss[idx] > median(claims$loss[idx]))

clusterGroups FALSE TRUE
            1   816  621
            2   691  687
            3   405  382
            4   886 1055
            5   493  499
            6   249  256
            7   462  481
            8   530  502
            9   468  517
```

Comment: Extraordinary !!

Comment: just subset the data.frame you get from the above..?

Comment: So, I need to calculate a new column sum to get the greatest after I do subset ??

Comment: yes you can do that. I just updated the answer, it's a matrix now, you can just do, results[order(-rowSums(results)),][1:3,]

Comment: or, you know the cluster number by doing table(clusterGroups).. check out https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html

Comment: Thank you so much, God bless you !!